# ngx-graph TypeError and ReferenceError on runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-charts, ngx-graph

I am using ngx-graphs with Angular 17 (currently there is an open PR for the angular 17 support but not merged so I used a forked version of the user made the PR (https://github.com/Kr0san89/ngx-graph) of ngx-charts that includes this change for the support in Angular 17).

I don't stumbled in any functional issues with the graph and data I am using but I have 2 runtime errors that I don't know if will result in some problems. My code does not deviate a lot from the ngx-graphs demos and I have no build errors.

Specifically

```
ERROR TypeError: hostElem.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at _GraphComponent.getContainerDims (/ui/node_modules/@kr0san89/ngx-graph/fesm2022/kr0san89-ngx-graph.mjs:2503:40)
    at _GraphComponent.basicUpdate (/ui/node_modules/@kr0san89/ngx-graph/fesm2022/kr0san89-ngx-graph.mjs:2478:25)
    at _GraphComponent.ngOnChanges (/ui/node_modules/@kr0san89/ngx-graph/fesm2022/kr0san89-ngx-graph.mjs:1641:10)
    at _GraphComponent.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4101:14)
    at callHookInternal (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5136:14)
    at callHook (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5167:9)
    at callHooks (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5118:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5068:9)
    at refreshView (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12351:21)
    at detectChangesInView$1 (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12560:9)
ERROR TypeError: hostElem.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at _GraphComponent.getContainerDims (/ui/node_modules/@kr0san89/ngx-graph/fesm2022/kr0san89-ngx-graph.mjs:2503:40)
    at _GraphComponent.basicUpdate (/ui/node_modules/@kr0san89/ngx-graph/fesm2022/kr0san89-ngx-graph.mjs:2478:25)
    at _GraphComponent.ngOnChanges (/ui/node_modules/@kr0san89/ngx-graph/fesm2022/kr0san89-ngx-graph.mjs:1641:10)
    at _GraphComponent.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4101:14)
    at callHookInternal (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5136:14)
    at callHook (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5167:9)
    at callHooks (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5118:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5068:9)
    at refreshView (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12351:21)
    at detectChangesInView$1 (/ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12560:9)
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I'm not sure how I can handle this, one thought was to debug this through changes directly from node_modules but I cannot see the reflected changes in the browser, I understand that they won't be reflected because the package has to be rebuilt again and angular has to understand it as new and reload it but i'm not exactly sure how to do this. Also I'm not sure if this problem is due to the Angular 17 or it is also present in the previous versions. I will also open an issue later in the official repository but cannot make a reproduction due to the forked repository. Any ideas on how I can at least debug this and/or make local changes to it?